# How to expand a UISearchBar when it becomes active

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar that needs to be compressed (see screenshot) and then expand to a larger size when it is touched or isActive.

How would I go about doing this? Currently my search bar is placed in the view via IB.

thanks

[image: UISearchBar screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding a NSNotifcation listener for the keyboard showing/hiding notifications and based on this adjust the UISearchBar frame:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(adjustFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(adjustFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

We need to remove the listener when the view is going to disappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

And now we need the 2 custom functions to adjust the frame:

```
- (void)adjustFrame:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    if ([[notification name] isEqual:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification]) {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake (100,50,100,self.searchBar.frame.size.Height);
    } 
    else  {
        //resize search bar
        self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake (10,50,200,self.searchBar.frame.size.Height);    
}

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Use the above code if you have only searchbar in the view. If there are textfield, TextView or any kind of UIObjects which brings up the keyboard this adjustFrame method will be invoked automatically.

Comment: You can very easily check if the first responder is the searchbar and if it's not (multiple elements showing the keyboard) stop the process..

Answer (score 3):

Use this delegate of the search bar :

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

  [self setTheSearchBarWithRect:newRect];//newRect is CGRect;
}

-(void)setTheSearchBarWithRect:(CGRect)frame{

   [UIView animateWithDuration:(1.5f)
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     yourSearchBar.frame   =   frame;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
}
```

and in the below delegate call the above function with its original frame.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar;
```

Comment: This doesn't restore the search frame back to the original, but I guess you can use the searchBarTextDidEndEditing delegate for this

Answer (score 1):

You should just change search bar frame (location and size) on editing start and ending.

for example:
on start

```
sbar.frame = CGRectMake(sbar.frame.origin.x - 100., sbar.frame.origin.y, sbar.frame.size.x + 100., sbar.frame.size.y);
```

on edit end just back control at original place:

```
sbar.frame = CGRectMake(sbar.frame.origin.x + 100., sbar.frame.origin.y, sbar.frame.size.x - 100., sbar.frame.size.y);
```